# ContentFlow javascript carousel - how to add text to image?

Tags: javascript, html, css, extjs, contentflow

I'm looking to make use of the excellent Javascript widget called ContentFlow:

http://jacksasylum.eu/ContentFlow/index.php

However, in my ExtJS application, I have a need to print text inside the images that are scrolling by.  Not being a CSS whiz, I'm really struggling to do this.  Any insights would be most welcome!

Answer (score 2):

I think that you should add the following styles in .caption class. Something like that may work.

```
.caption {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 125px;
}
```

Apart from that, it just an issue of playing around with the `bottom` value to position it at your will. Also, don't forget that you could add `left`, `right` and `top` attributes as well, if you need to.